# What's causing my games to sometimes exit to the homescreen?

Tags: crashes, sony-ericsson-xperia-ray

I have a Sony Ericsson Xperia Ray.

When i first bought the phone, it came with a 4GB class 2 microSD without a brand name.
I could play games without problems and it was pretty stable.

Then I bought a cheap 32GB microSD without any class. I moved my files from the old card into a new one by copy-pasting them. When I play games (mostly big-sized games) the games will sometimes suddenly crash to homescreen without any "force close" option.

Then I thought it was maybe because of the cheap microSD so I bought a new Transcend  32 GB class 10 microSDHC.  It is fast enough for HD games, and I'm satisfied with it, but the same problem happens - games will sometimes crash to homescreen.

Is this because of my storage space? Maybe I installed too much stuff on it? I have 80 MB free space. Maybe this is the cause?

My phone condition:

- Rooted
- No other modifications applied.

Comment: Please limit your question to be a single question. Your query about voice calls should be a separate question.

Comment: Get a logcat viewer off of Android Market (Catlog is decent) and launch it immediately after a game crashes.  See if you can find the actual error message associated with the crash.

Comment: The Android version might be helpful to know as well in this case: when it comes to logcat viewers, due to changes in the security regulations, they got trouble with Jelly Bean which need to be considered (if not updated then, they were no longer able to read logs). Also: How much RAM does your device have? What are the RAM conditions when the error occurs?

Answer (score 5):

If your foreground app is being closed without warning, the suspect is no other than Kernel. It generally happens when Kernel runs out of memory. In such case, Kernel reclaims memory by killing other apps, otherwise the device would be crashed. In such situation, Kernel doesn't respect multitasking (apps with background services, apps having icon in status bar etc) and in some cases, even foreground apps (when its very critical). When Kernel fails to do it due to CPU unavailability etc, the device really get crashed. This is how it works.

In your case, one or more reasons are responsible:

- You've a load of lots of background running apps which draw lot of memory even during game play.
- The game requires more resources than your device hardware provides. Its less likely because game runs most of times, but its possible that game does a lot of memory caching which outruns currently available memory.
- There's memory leakage bug in atleast one of your installed apps.

When it comes to fully filled big storage, system requires somewhat more resources to locate a file in it, but it doesn't cause this type of problem. You can reduce memory card size or files in it to lower down performance impact, but its not recommended. Its better to hunt down and remove always-running apps which are not extremely useful. Even if its useful, you should find its alternative which doesn't always run in background.

In the last, you can always install [CatLog](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nolanlawson.logcat) to see what happened after game crash. If you find it as alien language, Google it or ask here.

Comment: thank you so much, i will definitely try that. Currently downloading it.  :)

Answer (score 2):

In such cases I would highly suggest to try to replicate the problem while usb debugging is enabled. Install the android sdk which will give you the necessary tools to "logcat" what's happening. The messages might give you a clue what is causing the sudden shutdown of your application.

After having installed the sdk you can simply start the logging through Terminal/cmd by

> adb logcat

A picture for illustration (click to enlarge):

[image: Picture for illustration]

As suggested it might be a problem with low ram. Sony Ericsson Xperia S Phones sometimes feel sluggish especially if you use a lot of "widgets" such as the timeline and media player widget on your homescreen as they are quite ressource intensive. This might be indirectly linked to the shutdown of your games if there are many background services running there just won't be enough free ram for the game.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But i will try the catlog app first as i dont have android sdk on my computer.  My computer's performance is worse than my android lol.  But thank you so much, i might try it.

Comment: oh someone edited my question and actually changed the meaning a bit.  I was asking "is this because of my RAM?", yes i made a mistake that i said "RAM storage space" before, but what i meant was my RAM.  I still have about 14 gb of storage space.

Comment: Actually, you don't need to install the entire SDK for that -- all you need is the adb executable (I use it this way; it ships e.g. with root-exploits intended for Android 4.x).

Answer (score -3):

Download Advance Task Killer from Android Market. Then, open it, go to `Settings` and select `auto task kill`.

Comment: If possible, please provide a link to the app. :)

Comment: How shall a task killer be helpful here? "Auto-task-killing" is a **very bad** thing (enough posts about that, so I do not go into details here as they are not related to the question). In short: Task killers are only good for killing hanging tasks which hog resources and cannot be closed otherwise.